# How to setup the broadcast receiver to receive custom events from a particular package?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-source

Im working on  a system app in customized **AOSP10** build setup where I have a requirement to receive INTENT from an app partner. **The app is not included as part of the AOSP build.**

From the the **app partner (SenderApp A)** I'm sending the broadcast like the below and I don't have any specific entries in the AndroidManifest.xml with respect to this

**From app partner( SenderApp A ):**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction( "action_from_app_partner");
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.test.systemapp","com.test.systemapp.SystemAppReceiver"));
  sendBroadcast(intent,"custom.android.permission.MY_STATE_CHANGED");
```

**System App (Receiver App)**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <permission  android:name="custom.android.permission.MY_STATE_CHANGED" />
   <uses-permission  android:name="custom.android.permission.MY_STATE_CHANGED" />
```

**In the java code i use to register the Broadcast receiver**

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction("action_from_app_partner");
   registerReceiver(this, filter,"custom.android.permission.MY_STATE_CHANGED",null);
```

Im able to send broadcast from  **SenderApp A** to the  **SystemApp (Receiver App)**. But im also able to send this broadcast event from other apps too. For example if i create another app **SenderApp B** and use the broadcast snippet i shared above , the event is captured in the
Receiver side.

How do I setup the my receiver to receive from a particular package ?

Can someone please let me know if this approach is correct ? If not can you please suggest the proper way . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict to receive from a particular package, but [a set of apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#restrict-broadcasts-permissions).